Is there a rule of thumb for when to bake and when to not bake procedural textures?
I have been experimenting on an archvis project renderings. I have some procedural textures that have a relatively few nodes (less than fifteen), and some that are monsters (15-50 or more). I have run sample renders on some of the smaller ones that I have baked, I run the render baked, then change the material back to just nodes and many actually take longer to render than the unbaked.
It's usually just a nominal amount of time, seconds, but when animating, that multiplies render time really quick. The much larger node trees baked seem to always benefit from baking.
I get that some nodes are much more mathematically involved than others but, rather than test every material one by one.
Is there a basic rule of thumb used to go ahead and bake versus skip over so you can quickly focus on the largest node trees and save time baking? I'll be rendering in Cycles.

I guess: "is it slowing down my rendering?" is the key point, and this is so dependent on "everything" that there is probably no formula. By "everything", understand: node complexity, hardware speed, your patience and deadline. How much time loss are you willing to afford? How much time do you take baking (more or less than the extra processing?)

It's for an new web series. Set to broadcast time, 22 minutes for a half our show, about half will be video and a little less than half will be archvis animation so, a number of 10-30 second scenes of animation. I have a beefy computer RTX 3090, 64GB RAM, very good motherboard, SSD's, etc. I'm looking to develop my workflow to immediately skip baking some procedural and go right to baking large node trees without testing. Some would hit well; some would miss a bit, but I'm looking to settle into a balance that gets the better workflow.

There is no absolutely right or wrong answer here. Whether a procedural texture is faster or slower to render than an image texture depends on many factors. First of all, not all procedural textures have the same complexity and take the same time to calculate. Then the sheer amount of procedural textures you have to combine to get a result. A baked texture is one image, no matter if it was produced by one procedural texture or 10 combined ones before. And the speed of rendering an image can vary with its resolution and bit depth and even if it's a more or less compressed file format.

So even when you don't want to test it out manually, there is no real rule of thumb. Generally you might say, procedural textures can be scaled without getting problems like you have with image resolutions, so for very detailed or close-up shots you would need images with a very high resolution whereas procedural textures might use less resources no matter which scale, especially if they are only a few. But if you want to export models for Unity as FBX or OBJ  etc. then you need to bake image textures, because Blender's own procedural textures are not transferable with these file formats.
